# How to write a test for a VisualEditor.DynamicPickList class?

Tags: unit-test, picklist, dynamic-apex

I have this `DynamicPickList` class that creates picklist values based on what lookups have been put on the Contact object. It is used in the targetConfigs of a LWC. How do I write a test for this class? It didn't seem like you can just

```
public class Picklist_ContactLookups extends VisualEditor.DynamicPickList{
    String defaultVal = '-- none --';

    public override VisualEditor.DataRow getDefaultValue(){
        VisualEditor.DataRow defaultValue = new VisualEditor.DataRow(defaultVal, defaultVal);
        return defaultValue;
    }

    public override VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows getValues() {
        VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows lookupsList = new VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows();
        List<String> formLookups = Util.findAllLookupsOnContact();
        VisualEditor.DataRow noneValue = new VisualEditor.DataRow(defaultVal, defaultVal);
        lookupsList.addRow(noneValue);
        for (String lookup : formLookups) {
            VisualEditor.DataRow value = new VisualEditor.DataRow(lookup, lookup);
            lookupsList.addRow(value);
        }
        return lookupsList;
    }
}
```

I tried to call

```
 VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows rows = Picklist_ContactLookups.getValues();
```

from the test and got "Non static method cannot be referenced from a static context: VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows Picklist_ContactLookups.getValues()". The `Util.findAllLookupsOnContact();` already has its own test.

Answer (score 3):

You have to instantiate the class to call its member functions.

```
Picklist_ContactLookups pcl = new Picklist_ContactLookups();
VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows rows = pcl.getValues();
```

Then, just make assertions about the class's behavior as you would in any other unit test.